# dotnet not following system proxy settings

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, restsharp, fiddler-dev

I installed fiddler the other week, and now some HTTPs requests only work when Fiddler is open and running. When Fiddler is not open. I have gone into Windows system proxy settings and confirmed that the proxy server is off. Uninstalling fiddler does not fix it.

I also uninstalled Fiddler Everywhere and installed Fiddler Classic. Same thing, only works when Fiddler is running, only difference is the port number changes. It looks like dotnet core is caching the information somewhere that I cannot find.

I am using .net 6.0.3 and Visual Studio 2022. When running the same code on production server there is no issues. There should be no proxy server set.

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it. (127.0.0.1:8888)

[image: Proxy]

[image: LAN Settings]

UPDATE: Looks like RestSharp is caching the proxy?

Comment: Do you restart your .net program after changing the proxy settings are is your program a long-running service?

Comment: I've restarted the computer in between, and reset network adaptors